# ggplot cumulated value in barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to develop a bar chart that shows cumulated values for a couple of categories (in this case "a" and "b"). The chart itself looks ok, as the value for a is plotted at 10 and for b at 9.5, but the labels are off. Instead of the correct sum "9.5", the labels for b show the single values for b (1.5, 1, 5, 2).

So, the question is: how to tell ggplot that I want to see the cumulated values (sum) as the label and not each single value?

Best
paradroid

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mydf<-data.frame(col1=c("a","b", "b", "b", "b")
                 ,col2=c(10,1.5, 1, 5, 2))


barchart <- function(df, v1, v2) 
  {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = v1, y = v2, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = v2)) +
    coord_flip()
    }


bchart <- barchart(mydf, mydf$col1, mydf$col2)
print(bchart)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the dplyr steps suggested by Peter, we could also use `stat_summary(fun = sum)` to calculate the sums.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mydf<-data.frame(col1=c("a","b", "b", "b", "b")
                 ,col2=c(10,1.5, 1, 5, 2))


barchart <- function(df, v1, v2) 
{
  ggplot(df, aes(x = {{v2}}, y = {{v1}})) + 
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
    stat_summary(
      fun = sum, geom = "text",
      aes(label = after_stat(x)),
      hjust = -0.1
    )
}


barchart(mydf, col1, col2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I swapped your `x` and `y` and deleted the `coord_flip()`. This is mostly to encourage people to make use of the bidirectional geoms feature.

Answer (score 2):

You could summarise the data within the function using `dplyr`, assuming you do not need to see the build up of each bar.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

mydf<-data.frame(col1=c("a","b", "b", "b", "b")
                 ,col2=c(10,1.5, 1, 5, 2))

barchart <- function(df, v1, v2)
  {
    df %>% 
    group_by({{v1}}) %>%
    summarise(v2 = sum({{v2}})) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = {{v1}}, y = v2)) + 
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = v2)) +
    coord_flip()

}

bchart <- barchart(mydf, col1, col2)

bchart
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>